# Chrome Extension — chrome.storage API: regexes serialize incorrectly

Tags: regex, serialization, google-chrome-extension

From the [chrome.storage documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) on `StorageArea.set`'s `object` argument:

> An object which gives each key/value pair to update
>   storage with. Any other key/value pairs in storage will not be
>   affected. Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected.
>   Values with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize
>   to {}, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and
>   Regex (serialize using their String representation).

According to the docs, passing a regex as a value in the object should serialize and deserialize when setting/getting from chrome.storage.

However:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'regex': /abc/ig}, function(){

    chrome.storage.local.get('regex', function(response) {
        console.log(response['regex']);
    });

});
```

This returns `Object {}` in the console. Is this a bug?

Comment: http://crbug.com/new is the right place to go.

Comment: Reported as [http://crbug.com/380964](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380964).